# CSS not formatting accordingly

Tags: html, css

Website: http://uniformserver.com

The bottom footer is not formatting accordingly. It should be at the end but when the site loads, it comes up the the image size.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7caX.jpg

Should look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5s3L.jpg

If you navigate to another page, it corrects itself.

Footer CSS

```
footer {
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: default;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
    footer p {
        color: #c1c1c1;
        font-size: 11px;
        padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
        background: #f7f7f7;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
        display: inline;
        -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-transition:color 0.2s ease-in, background 0.2s ease-in;  
    -moz-transition:color 0.2s ease-in, background 0.2s ease-in;  
    -o-transition:color 0.2s ease-in, background 0.2s ease-in;  
    transition:color 0.2s ease-in, background 0.2s ease-in;
    }
    footer p:hover {
        background: #f1f1f1;
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        color: #999;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the respective css for footer??

Comment: footer {
        clear: both;
        padding-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: default;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

Comment: footer{margin:0px auto}

Comment: Drop the rest in there ?

Comment: Didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer has some padding at the bottom. If you reduce it, it will get closer to the bottom of the page.

`footer.container { padding-bottom: 0; }` would be a footer that touches the bottom completely, and `footer.container { padding-bottom: 15px; }` is probably close to what you're looking for.

However, because your page doesn't have a lot of content on it, your footer will appear higher when there just isn't enough content on the page to fill the full viewport.

A quick trick to experiment with this is zooming in and out on your browser. You can use the `ctrl` or `cmd` + `+/-` shortcuts.

Comment: You have `padding-bottom: 30px;` set on your `footer`. See `base.css`:`570`